# What is the best way to use Spring and ElasticSearch?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, lucene

I have to implement some application by using springframework.
All i have to do is just select from repository (no RDBMS, maybe lucene or elastic search core) and Display some view pages for customers. that is not save or update but read.

What is the best way to select for repositories in spring framework ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spring-data-elasticsearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch) which is the Spring Data implementation for ElasticSearch.

In order to get started, you may like to refer to https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-elasticsearch-example/ which explains the integration with an example. Although it is a bit old but provide you with enough information to get it working.

Comment: thx :) i also think that spring-data-elasticsearch is the best way to implement my app :D